# Import data from Excel file in Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, excel, import

I am using VS2010, Silverlight 5.0

I am trying to Import Data from Excel file to Grid, for that I am using an 'OpenFileDialog'. User can Input Excel file using OpenFileDialog like this

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.Multiselect = false;
dlg.Filter = "Excel Sheet(*.xls)|*.xls|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
bool bResult = (bool)dlg.ShowDialog();
if (!bResult)
    return "";

FileInfo info = dlg.File;
StatusText.Text = info.Name;

Stream s = info.OpenRead();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
string xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

In Case of Microsoft Excel Format 2003 or 2007(.xls file) above code works fine and gives me values from Excel in a string.

But in case of Microsoft Excel Format 2010(.xlsx file) the `reader.ReadToEnd()` does not return values in proper format so the next line, give me following Error.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1'
```

How can I solve this error, or what is the best way to import data from excel?